# How to get information about operating system and web server using curl

Tags: curl

How can i get that? I need the output is an array that include all information about the system server like type of operating system and type of web server.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what are called server headers using the I flag. These will often give you the webserver and sometimes OS, assuming the website does not use a proxy service like Cloudflare.

For example:

`curl -I https://www.google.com`

Comment: I meant in php native, not terminal